# List of Lists of Lists of Lists in Java

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I'm trying to store the Civil Spanish Code.

It is divided in this way:

```
Books

----Chapters

--------Articles
```

OR

```
Books

----Titles

--------Chapters

-------------Articles
```

OR

```
Books

----Titles

--------Chapters

-------------Sections

-----------------Articles
```

Books, titles, chapters and sections have to store an `int identifier` and a `String with the name of the book`, `title`, etc. The number of elements are variable since some books have more chapters than others, for example.

`Articles` have to store and `int identifier` and a `String` with the content of the article.

I would apreciate an example of `declaration and usage` (in data, out data) of the structure since (for me) it's a bit complex.

Comment: May you want to use XML for that?

Comment: XML will be the best way for manipulating this kind of data

Comment: I doubt nesting lists is really useful here.  I would have a single `List<Record>` and I would add indexes, using Maps, as required.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend XML as I imagine the Civil Spanish Code to be quiet extensive. XML doesn't do so well on large amount of data (as it is text based)...

Comment: @brimborium JSON is also a good candidate

Comment: @Teejay Yes, it is much better than XML (though less human readable which is fine in this context), but it is still text based. You need *O(1)* access to the articles which can not be supported by any of those text based storage systems (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather create a Tree structure of Nodes, as follows (this is a psedo-code that can help you):

```
public interface Node {
    public int getId();
    public String getName();

    public void saveTo(SaveVisitor visitor);
}

public abstract class AbstractNode {
    public List<Node> children;

    //Getters
    public List<Node> getChildren() { return children; }

    public void addChild(Node node) {
        if (children == null) {
            children = new ArrayList<Node>();
        }

        children.add(node);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveTo(SaveVisitor visitor) {
        if (visitor != null) {
            visitor.setId(getId());
            visitor.setName(getName());

            if (children != null) {
                for (Node child: children) {
                    child.saveTo(visitor);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public class Book extends AbstractNode {

}

public class Title extends AbstractNode {

}

public class Chapter extends AbstractNode {

}

public class Section extends AbstractNode {

}

public class Article extends AbstractNode {

}
```

Your `SaveVisitor` can be any visitor that accepts `ID`, `Name`, and the subclasses can be of any format (XML, JSON, Structured plaintext, Excel, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, just a question. How do you know what kind of children youre adding? Or you just don't care? I ask this because when I use the info I'll need to know if the Chapter children I'm accessing is an article or a section.

Comment: For now, the children are generic, but you can encapsulate your abstract method to protected, and create necessary `add` method that is more specific to the `Node` that you want.

Answer (score 1):

What about use classes for this? Well, everything is doable with just primitive types and containers, but why? It is far less readable then.

```
public class Book {
   private int id;
   private List<Chapter> chapters;
   private List<Title> titles;

   // getters/setters/constructor
}

public class Chapter {
   private int id;
   private List<Section> section;
   private List<Article> articles;

   // getters/setters/constructor
}

public class Title {
   private int id;
   private List<Chapter> chapters;

   // getters/setters/constructor
}

public class Section {
   private int id;
   private List<Article> articles;

   // getters/setters/constructor
}
```

To me it is the easiest way. The version of The Elite Gentleman is little bit more complex, but on the other hand more robust to change of the domain model (adding new types or changing the relations).

Comment: When I first started thinking I thought of a structure like this, but thought it was unefficient. Is it?

Comment: You can create a generic class that has an `id` property, instead of always entering an `id` in all classes.

Comment: Unefficient?  Compared to Lists of Lists of Lists of Lists?  Wrong again.

Comment: Can anyone make an example on including data in the structure of jkremser? I'm doing a parser which reads a txt like this:

TITLE 1: BLA BLABLA
CHAPTER 1: BLABLA
ART1
AR2
ART3
...

Thanks a lot. I'm starting with java

Comment: What about the news The thing would be that I have to parse a text file like book->all the titles->all the articles; book.. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be a `Map<Index, Entry>` with `Entry` being the text (maybe a simple string or something similar) and `Index` storing the *coordinates*:

```
class Index {
  public int book, title, chapter, section, article;
}
```

You would then implement `Index` to be comparable (`equals()/compareTo()`) and maybe supply some methods to navigate to the book (`getNextChapter(Index)`, `isLastArticle(Index)`, etc.)

You can also put those helper methods into a separate class (like a `CivilSpanishCodeHandler`) to keep it all clean.

Also, a `Tree` would pop into mind because it would be the most natural representation. Although I would recommend coding your own tree structure to implement all the above mentioned helper methods into the tree.